# Contour plot of 2d point data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, multidimensional-array

I have set of data (values from 0 to 1) with corresponding coordinates, and I want to plot those data on map with matplotlib's `contourf`.

The problem is that I have 30-40 data points and a coordinate grid of 270x480 and those contours looks like tiny dots.

So I need to interpolate data some way, so lonely dot will look like little spot, and those spots will merge together.

I've read a lot of samples of interpolating, but almost all of them about one-dimensional data or some very complicated examples.

I've tried `ndimage.gaussian_filter(array,3)`, but it makes my dots even less.

So, this how it look like:
(https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2019/09/6939ee7e1291c684b7a467ff610a7235.png)
and this is how it should look:
(https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2019/09/445833329d9f1f332e1603f25efe7b1e.png)

edit: I've tried gaussian blur (`ndimage.gaussian_filter`), it makes a great blurred picture, but with loss of data - values at known coordinates became wrong

edit2: I've make some application of scipy.interpolate.griddata, and there are source:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

FR = np.array([[0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 4.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 7.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
               [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000]])
points = []
values = []
for x in range(33):
    for y in range(20):
        points.append([x,y])
        if FR[x][y] > 0.0:
            values.append(FR[x][y])
        else:
            values.append(0)
            pass
X, Y = np.mgrid[0:32:33j, 0:19:20j]
x, y = np.mgrid[0:32:66j, 0:19:40j]
grid = interpolate.griddata(points, values, (x,y), method='cubic')
fig, axes = pl.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 4))
c1 = axes[0].contourf(X, Y, FR)
pl.colorbar(c1, ax=axes[0]);
c2 = axes[1].contourf(x, y, grid)
#c2 = axes[1].contourf(x, y, grid, levels = c1.levels)
pl.colorbar(c2, ax=axes[1]);
pl.show()
```

Those predefined array looks awful, but gives an idea of my dataset.
So, [that](https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2019/09/2b1a3418fb69f97839397bae5fc505ee.png) is how it looks like.

It firstly broke data (now points of maximum have value 6.4, not 7), and secondly didn't make any significant blur - between points of data there are still a lot of almost-zero-values. And not to mention those strange stripes of negative data.

Is there are some way to enhance this interpolation to make those spots in one spot?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I got a question: Where's your code? And where's your plotted data?
I'm using answers since comments require 50 rep. I'll just edit this once you deliver on your code.

Comment: emm and what you want to see in my code? It's just "plt.contourf(x,y,array); plt.show()". And I've described my data and show an image

Comment: just post everything, including import statements. One of the rules around here is that you need to provide a minimal working example that others can run on their pc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to interpolate the data onto a regular grid. Have a look at [this Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/agile-geoscience/xlines/blob/master/notebooks/11_Gridding_map_data.ipynb). Here's the meat of it (using another dataset):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf

# Load the data.
df = pd.read_csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/6dyfc4fl5slhgry/ZoneA.dat?raw=1',
                 sep=' ',
                 header=9,
                 usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3],
                 names=['x', 'y', 'thick', 'por']
                )

# Build a regular grid with 500-metre cells.
extent = x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = [df.x.min()-1000, df.x.max()+1000,
                                       df.y.min()-1000, df.y.max()+1000]
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[x_min:x_max:500, y_min:y_max:500]

# Make the interpolator and do the interpolation.
rbfi = Rbf(df.x, df.y, df.por)
di = rbfi(grid_x, grid_y)

# Make the plot.
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.imshow(di.T, origin="lower", extent=extent)
cb = plt.scatter(df.x, df.y, s=60, c=df.por, edgecolor='#ffffff66')
plt.colorbar(cb, shrink=0.67)
plt.show()
```

[This notebook](https://github.com/agile-geoscience/xlines/blob/master/notebooks/10_Contour_maps.ipynb) shows you how to make a contour plot.